# Java - Result not outputting correctly

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to finish a program that displays the average, hottest, & coldest temperatures of the week, and also displays which days are the hottest and coldest. The user enters in 7 temperatures from Sun - Sat. It is almost working but it seems as though there is a bug in the method near the bottom called searchTemp, this method sees how many times the highest/lowest temperature occurred in the array of temperatures, and then creates an array of size needed, and then it iterates over all the values, storing the indexes at which the high/low temperatures occurred in the original array, it then returns the new array with the values of the index locations. Ideally I would map these values to an array containing the strings Sunday through Saturday and print out all the days that the temperature was the highest or lowest. The issue is that right now if the user enters say 18 for the highest and then they enter 18 again, instead of the program outputting something like "Monday Wednesday" it outputs Wednesday Wednesday"

Can anyone help me?

```
    public static int[] searchTemp(int[] array, int key) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if(array[i] == key)
                    count++;
        }
        int[] indices = new int[count];
        for(int j = 0; j < indices.length; j++) {
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if(array[i] == key)
                    indices[j] = i;
            }
        }
        return indices;
        }

}
```

Comment: Please divide this chunk into paragraphs.

Comment: take a look at this line, `indices[i] = i;` `i` value range is between `0` to `array.length` . while `indices` size might be < `array.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The searchTemp should be changed as following:

```
public static int[] searchTemp(int[] array, int key) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if(array[i] == key)
                    count++;
        }
        int[] indices = new int[count];
        for(int j = 0; j < indices.length; j++) {
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if(array[i] == key) {
                    if(j > 0 && indices[j - 1] == i){
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        indices[j] = i;
                        break;
                    }                   
                }                    
            }
        }
        return indices;
   }
```

This will return the correct hottest/coldest.
Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is here

```
    int[] indices = new int[count];
    for(int j = 0; j < indices.length; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i] == key)
                indices[i] = i;  <---------
        }
    }
```

should be 
indices[j] not i as you are using the inner array's length on this.

Comment: Ah good catch thank you, that did solve the out of bounds issue, although now if the user enters say 18 for the highest and then they enter 18 again, instead of the program outputting something like "Monday Wednesday" it outputs Wednesday Wednesday" @Eliseo